# Is my HDD to SSD cloning method technically correct?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, migration

I have an HP laptop with planned HDD to SSD migration with Windows 8 installed.

1. **Source** - HDD - 500GB - **SATA** - I can put this in my server and save it to a file.
2. **Destination** - SSD - 120GB - **M.2** - I can't put this into my server.

I plan on doing the following in a few days:

1. <strike>Delete the two HP partitions at the end of the disk.</strike>
2. Shrink the system (C:) partition using some software for Windows below 100GB.
3. Using Linux computer and `pv` utility as follows:

   ```
   pv < /dev/sourceDrive > /dev/destinationDrive
   ```

   Making 1:1 copy of the drive.

   Expecting it to *fail* of course at the end of the SSD drive, i.e. at 120 GB. But since there will be no data on the source disk there, that is no problem, right?

That's about it. Is it a sound idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out, my method worked **flawlessly**. Minor corrections follow.

I did not have to delete the 2 HP partitions. And I advise you not to do so, they might be handy.

Just shrink the system partition (C:) below adequate value, depending on how small your SSD in comparison to your original HDD is. And move the 2 HP partitions towards the system partition.

So that you then have like 400GB free space **at the end** in case of 500GB HDD or something similar in case of other sizes.

On the source computer, in order to do so, you can use any Windows partition tool available, I will just mention, what I used: [MiniTool Partition Wizard Free Edition](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html).

On the server just copy the shrunk source drive into a file with the [`pv` (man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) utility.

[`pv` (man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) has advantages like showing progress or ETA for instance.

With a live Linux on the destination computer, plug your external hard drive you have saved the source drive file onto.

And then copy with the aforementioned command or if unavailable, you can always use `cat`, the source drive file onto the destination drive.

Just a note to impatient ones: When the [`pv` (man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) fails for the whole drive does not fit into destination of course, which was the point from the beginning, it says something like:

> ```
> no space left on the device
> ```

It will then wait for the buffer to write into the destination, which in my case took 1-2 minutes. Just be patient, then safely shut down the computer and you can happily swap the HDD for an SSD in the laptop.

---

### UPDATE

After such operation, you will always want to / have to run `gdisk` on the new medium and fix PMBR, etcetera with write!

Answer (score -3):

Actually, to clone HDD to SSD using minitool partition wizard, there is no need to shrink C:, because this program considers file size but not partition size. That is to say, as long as the SSD can hold contents on the source disk, clone is available.